# Setting values to UILabels in Table View cell iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitableview

I am new to Swift and iOS development, sorry for the beginner question. I'm attempting to set two UILabel text values and an UIImageView in my Table View Cells. I have the data coming from the API `www.thecocktaildb.com`

I am searching and retrieving the data from the search bar like: `http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita`

I do not know how to get those values to the UILabels/UIImageView. Can someone point me in the right direction? Or if I'm setting it up incorrectly in my storyboard. Thanks!

Attached below is my SearchViewController with the search bar, table view, and the table view cell.

[My Search View Controller in my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhAYi.png)

Attached bellow is my SearchViewController.swift file

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var SearchBar: UISearchBar!

    // search in progress or not
    var isSearching : Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for subView in self.SearchBar.subviews
        {
            for subsubView in subView.subviews
            {

                if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField
                {
                    textField.attributedPlaceholder  = NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: ""))

                }
            }
        }

        // set search bar delegate
        self.SearchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if self.SearchBar.text!.isEmpty {

            // set searching false
            self.isSearching = false

        }else{

            // set searghing true
            self.isSearching = true

            let userSearchInput = self.SearchBar.text!.lowercaseString

            let newString = userSearchInput.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "%20", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

            let postEndpoint: String = "http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=" + newString

            guard let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint) else {
                print("Error: cannot create URL")
                return
            }

            let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                guard let responseData = data else {
                    print("Error: did not receive data")
                    return
                }
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("error calling GET on www.thecocktaildb.com")
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
                let post: NSDictionary
                do {
                    post = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData,
                        options: []) as! NSDictionary
                } catch  {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    return
                }

                var count = 1
                if let drinks = post["drinks"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                    for drink in drinks {
                        if let strDrink = drink["strDrink"] as? String {
                            print(String(count) + ". " + strDrink)
                            count++
                        }
                        if let strCategory = drink["strCategory"] as? String {
                            print("    Category: " + strCategory)
                        }
                        if let strDrinkThumb = drink["strDrinkThumb"] as? String {
                            print("    Thumbnail Image: " + strDrinkThumb)
                        }
                    }
                }

            })
            task.resume()

        }

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }

    // hide kwyboard when search button clicked
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.SearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    // hide keyboard when cancel button clicked
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.SearchBar.text = ""
        self.SearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

An example of the data I get when I print to the console:

```
1. Margarita
    Category: Ordinary Drink
    Thumbnail Image: http://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/wpxpvu1439905379.jpg
2. Margarita #2
    Category: Ordinary Drink
3. Blue Margarita
    Category: Ordinary Drink
    Thumbnail Image: http://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/qtvvyq1439905913.jpg
4. Peach Margarita
    Category: Cocktail
5. Midori Margarita
    Category: Ordinary Drink
6. Golden Margarita
    Category: Cocktail
7. Purple Margarita
    Category: Ordinary Drink
8. Mansion Margarita
    Category: Ordinary Drink
9. JimPop's Margarita
    Category: Ordinary Drink
10. Catalina Margarita
    Category: Cocktail
11. Ultimate Margarita
    Category: Cocktail
12. Whitecap Margarita
    Category: Other/Unknown
    Thumbnail Image: http://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/srpxxp1441209622.jpg
13. Frozen Margarita #1
    Category: Ordinary Drink
14. Frozen Margarita #2
    Category: Ordinary Drink
15. Top Shelf Margarita
    Category: Cocktail
16. BlackJack Margarita
    Category: Ordinary Drink
17. Strawberry Margarita
    Category: Ordinary Drink
    Thumbnail Image: http://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/tqyrpw1439905311.jpg
18. Bartender's Margarita
    Category: Ordinary Drink
19. The Perfect Margarita #1
    Category: Cocktail
20. The Perfect Margarita #2
    Category: Cocktail
21. RumRunner's Easy Margarita
    Category: Cocktail
22. Hand-Shaken Margarita on the Rocks
    Category: Ordinary Drink
23. Ken and Kirsten's top shelf Margarita
    Category: Ordinary Drink
```

Comment: You'll need to set up your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It appears as though you're using a vanilla `UITableViewCell`, so you'll need outlets on your `TableViewController` in order to set the labels via `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: When I add the three outlets to my searchviewcontroller.swift file, I get the Error: Illegal Configuration: The DrinkName outlet from the SearchViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content. @AdrianB

Answer (score 0):

UITableViews work on a pull model so you you need to store drinks into an array variable on the view controller where you are currently printing the result. Then call reloadData on the table view. To store the drinks in typesafe way create a Drink model class with name and category etc as properties. Then in numberOfRowsInSection return the drinks.count and in cellForRowAtIndexPath get the drinks[indexPath.row] which you should be able to get the name etc. from and use that to populate the labels in the tableviewcell.  Getting the image is more complicated since you'll need to make another network request but once you get the text working you will have made good progress.

Comment: When I add the three outlets to my searchviewcontroller.swift file, I get the Error: Illegal Configuration: The DrinkName outlet from the SearchViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content. @Dallas Johnson

Comment: To start with try using one the default UITableviewCells which would be the one inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. Then you can just the the text for the built in text labels and not need any outlets to uilabels. Look here for more details https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/